# Can I make a dict of connections to database?

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlalchemy

I need to parse some db info from yml file and iteratively create several connections. The problem is - how to store them? Can I make a dict of connections?

for example:

```
for k,v in dbs_info.items():
   connections[k] = dbclass(v) # here we create engine
```

I need something like this to address to connections

```
conn = {'db1': conn1,'db2':conn2}
```

Comment: Of course. You can put anything in a dictionary.

Comment: Yes you can! Pass that dict around...

Answer (score 0):

DICT like you suggested as "conn" should work.

conn['db1'] value is the connection module (session).